# Compile-Time Constant Expected for Template Class With "static const" Identifier

Tags: c++

The goal is to write a meta program that determines whether or not a class has any virtual functions, a fairly easy task. My code is below.

```
template <typename T>
class HasVirtual :
    public T
{
public:
    static const bool has_virtual;
    virtual void doit() {}
};

template <typename T>
bool const HasVirtual<T>::has_virtual = sizeof(T) == sizeof(HasVirtual<T>);
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I try and use this elsewhere, like so:

```
template <typename T, bool isVirtual = HasVirtual<T>::has_virtual>
class PointerCopy
{
public:
    static T *copy(const T *x)
    {
        return new T(*x);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class PointerCopy<T, true>
{
public:
    static T *copy(const T *x)
    {
        return x->copy();
    }
};
```

I get the error `error C2975: 'isVirtual' : invalid template argument for 'PointerCopy', expected compile-time constant expression` even though `has_virtual` is defined with the `static const` identifier. I ended up "cheating" and defining another class like so:

```
template <typename T>
class VirtualDerived :
    public T
{
public:
    virtual void fun() {}
};

template <typename T>
class HasVirtual
{
public:
    static const bool has_virtual = sizeof(T) == sizeof(VirtualDerived<T>);
};
```

Which works perfectly. Still, I would like to know why I was getting this issue (or if this is an issue with the Visual Studio 2012 compiler). This seems kind of silly to be legitimate: defining a constant outside of the class shouldn't make it no longer a constant.

Comment: So you want to create a copy of [`std::is_polymorphic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic)?

Comment: Perhaps. This is an old exam question I'm going over that took way too long to get to compile...

Comment: And that's beside the point and has nothing to do with what I'm asking here

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: At the very end. Why defining constant `has_virtual` outside of the class made the compiler think that it's not a compile-time constant

Comment: Apparently yes, this is a compiler bug. The standard doesn't seem to require a const static member to be in-class initialized in order to be a constant expression. Other compilers do not produce an error here either. I was almost sure MSVC is right in this case, but no.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it out in gcc as well and alas, no errors! Also, gcc let me define `has_virtual` inside of the `HasVirtual<T>` class (Visual Studio gave me 'not defined' errors). Weird; Visual Studio it the one that's generally more forgiving of mistakes...